# rest_framework_simplejwt post to an APIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have this settings:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

And this view:

```py
class Config(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'config' in request.GET.dict():
            if os.path.isfile(settings.CONFIG):
                yaml = read_config(settings.CONFIG)
                return Response(yaml)
            else:
                return Response({
                    "success": False,
                    "error": "config file not found!"})
        else:
            return Response({"success": False})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'data' in request.data:
            print(request.data['data'])

        return Response({"success": False})
```

With axios I manage my api calls, for example:

```js
axios.post('api/config/?config', { data: obj, headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + rootState.auth.jwtToken } })
```

The problem is now, that I can not post data. I get an **Unauthorized** (401) error and in the response message it says: `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

Can you please tell me, what I'm missing here and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: jb_alvarado, you told us nothing about how you store obtained token on the client-side. It seems you don't do this.

Comment: On client side I use vue.js and I store the tokens in [store](https://github.com/ffplayout/ffplayout-gui/blob/v2.0.0-dev/ffplayout/frontend/store/auth.js) and localstorage. When I use **axios.get(...)** it works just normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- What is AUTH_HEADER_TYPES in settings.py ? Bearer or JWT. If JWT you must change header auth type.

2- Did you provide authenticate and obtain token ?

Solution:

Axios Post request assumes that the second parameter is data and third parameter is config. you sent header in second parameter. you can set the headers in the config.

```
axios.post(url, data, config)
```

change your axios.post to:

```
axios.post('api/config/?config', { data: obj }, {
headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + rootState.auth.jwtToken }})
```

Comment: Yunus Emre Cevik, you need to ask questions via comments not via answers

Comment: I have not explicit set AUTH_HEADER_TYPES, but when I run a **get** command instead of an **post** command, it works like is should.

Comment: try this => axios.post('api/config/?config', { data: obj }, {headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + rootState.auth.jwtToken }})